# Is it safe to use --blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false for e2e automation tests?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, e2e-testing, chrome-options

According to your experience, is it safe to use --blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false for e2e automation tests?
See the param in
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/frame/Settings.in

> imagesEnabled initial=true, invalidate=ImageLoading

What exactly this swith doing?
Is there any disadvantage to disable loading image during automated test, due to network issue? (outside of visual regressions test and screenshot creation)
Should it be any impact on test execution if images are disabled?